# How do I join the selected items in multiple list boxes with the user text entered in text box in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

**Goal**:Is to display Project name, formed by joining list box selected items with user entered text in the text box and display it as a `label`.

**Description:** I am creating a windows for App, which has two `listboxes` displaying Firstname-lbA & Lastname- lbB along with a `textbox` for the user to enter packet name.

**For example:** If I select an item(first name)from the `listbox` A i.e. "XXX", select an item(last name)from the `listbox` B i.e. "YYY" and enter text in the `Textbox` i.e. "PKT-100" & click create `button` I would want to display the Project name as XXX-YYY-PKT-100.

**checking conditions:**
If no Item in lbA is selected then display:YYY-PKT-100.
If no Item in Lb B is seleected then display :XXX-PKT-100. 
If no Text is entered the display: XXX-YYY.
No spaces/double dashes are allowed.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with your suggestions.

Thanks!!

Code:

```
FirstNamespace Project
{
    public partial class ProjectTool : Form
    {   
        public List<FirstName> ltfirstname { get; set; }
        public List<LastName> ltlastname { get; set; }

        public FirstName SelectedFirstname => (FirstName)lbGetFirstName.SelectedItem
        public LastName SelectedLastname => (LastName)lbGetLastName.SelectedItem;

        public projecTool()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();

            ltfirstname = GetFirstNames();
            lbGetFirstName.DataSource = ltfirstname;

            ltlastname  = GetLastNames();
            lbGetLastName.DataSource = ltlastname;

        }

        public List<FirstName> GetFirstNames()
        {
            List<FirstName> fnames = new List<FirstName>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\FirstNames.csv"))
            {
                string line;
                try
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] columns = line.Replace("\"","").Split(',');
                        if (columns.Length >= 1)
                        {
                            var name = new FirstName();
                            name.FirstName = columns[0];
                            fnames.Add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                return fnames;
            }
        }
        public List<LastName> GetlastNames()
        {
            List<LastName> lnames = new List<LastName>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\LastNames.csv"))
            {
                string line;
                try
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] columns = line.Replace("\"","").Split(',');
                        if (columns.Length >= 1)
                        {
                            var lname = new LastName();
                            lname.LastName = columns[0];
                            lnames.Add(lname);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                return lnames;
            }
        }

        public void CreateprojectName()
        {
            // Create project name as Firstname-Lastname-Packetname
                //if project name already exists then check for correctness/update.
                // Check -> if there are double dashes/spaces in the Project name
        }

        private void lbGetFirstName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void lbGetlastName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void txtPacketName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void create_projectname_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That all seems very straightforward to me, so I'm not sure where you would have run into trouble with it. What exactly are you having trouble with? Please show us the code you tried.

Comment: This should get you started: 1. Create a form, 2. Put the controls on it, 3. Handle the events. 4. Compile and debug. That is Windows Forms programming in a nutshell.

Comment: @EdPlunkett. I have added my code. As of now, I am able to populate my list boxes with items and not able to understand how to get the user entered data from the text boxes and join it to the Listbox selected items. Kindly,suggest me a way design my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple for [listBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) use SelectedItem & for [textBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) use Text property.

```
private void create_projectname_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbGetFirstName.SelectedItems.Count==0)
    {
        label1.Text = "YYY-PKT-100";
    }
    if (lbGetlastName.SelectedItems.Count==0)
    {
        label1.Text = "XXX-PKT-100";
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        label1.Text = "XXX-YYY";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = lbGetFirstName.SelectedItem + "-" + listBox2.SelectedItem + "-" + lbGetlastName.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me with your suggestions on my code? Thanks

Comment: I think thats what i tried to. What kind of help exactly you want? Are you getting error?

Comment: Thanks for the help it is working!! but there is a small issue. If i select multiple Firstnames in lbGetFirstname it is giving me an error. How would I be able to get multiple selected names from lbGetFirstName? 
For example: if I select "XXX" and "ZZZ" from lbGetFirstName, i want my project name to look like
"XXX-ZZZ-lbGetlastName.Item-lbGetlastName.Text".

Comment: @Rck7 `lbGetFirstName.SelectedItems`. Write a loop, learn to use String.Join(), learn LINQ -- it's time for you to start learning programming.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am trying to use LINQ as suggested, I am running in to an error. i.e. cannot convert from string to int. Not able to figure out whats going wrong. Kindly, help.
here is my code:

if (lbGetFirstName.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                var sl = lbGetFirstName.SelectedIndices
                       .OfType<string>()
                       .Select(i => ((FirstName)lbGetFirstName.Items[i]).name);
                string result = string.Join("-", sl);
            }

Comment: @Rck7 Go back and read my last comment as many times as you need to, and as carefully as you need to, until you understand what you did wrong. I told you to do something. You did something different. Do what I told you instead. Don't just stare at it, process each word individually one at a time.